# Dual cell protection using DW01

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, low-battery

I am using GS7001B-84 dual cell charger to charge battery. Now I want to protect these two cells. I have DW01 battery protection IC and AP2302B N channel mosfet. How can I protect battery using these components?
[image: Schematic of charging and protection of dual cell].
Help me if I am wrong with my schematic.

Answer (score 1):

As I have tested, it is possible to protect two cells using two DW01 circuits, each protecting one cell. On the above schematic I have wrongly connected the GND pin of IC. It should be connected to the -ve terminal of the battery. The correct schematic is as shown below:

[image]

As I have tested the DW01 protection module found in market, when battery voltage is at 2.5V the overall voltage of the system immediately drops to zero but when it is greater than 4.2V, the overall voltage become somehow greater than supply voltage. I believe the overall voltage should be 0 in case of overcharge as well.

Comment: To me it is not clear how this works together. Can you provide a schematic, that contains all elements with their connections and where the MOSFETS will disconnect?

Comment: In case of overcharge, if what you say was true there would be no way to come out of overcharge state. Instead, in case of over charge DW01 closes the circuit in the direction that charges the battery further, yet keeps discharge path open. Contrary in case of over discharge, it closes the path to further discharge but lets current flow in the direction that charges battery to come out of over discharge situation.